# how to change select option's height and hover background color

Tags: html, css

```
<select name="mySelect" class="select-min">
   <option value="0">please select</option>
   <option value="1">item1</option>
   <option value="2">item2</option>
   <option value="3">item3</option>
   <option value="4">item4</option>
   <option value="5">item5</option>
</select>
```

I want to change the option's height and background color when mouse over the option,I tried many times ,but failed

Comment: class="select-min"? can you show us this CSS class?

Comment: you cannot change option height, because it's browser control. you could change background on simple :hover, but it's not visible because of browser's native hover

Comment: Duplicate...Even the answer is duplicate....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<select>` or `<option>` HTML tag are rendering itself the time of webpage load. So You can not change the style for these elements.

Answer (score -1):

```
Please try this :-

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".select-min option").mouseover(function () {
      $(this).css({ "background-color": "black", "color": "white", "height": "32"});
    });

    $(".select-min option").mouseout(function () {
      $(this).css({ "background-color": "white", "color": "black", "height": "5" });
    });
 });

Let me know if it doesn't work.
```

Answer (score -3):

For the Height, i don't think it's possible.
For the hover:

```
select:hover { background-color: blue; }
```